# Linq query with multiple OR conditions in multiple joins

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have gone through a number of answers but haven't found anything that helps me with this. I understand that the "OR" part should happen in the Where clause, not the join itself, but unfortunately that doesn't look like a possibility for my query.

With these two tables, drastically simplified for this question:

```
Claim: FKeyID int, CKeyID int, ICode varchar(100), IName varchar(100)
Lookup: LFKeyID int, LCKeyID int, LICode varchar(100), LIName varchar(100)
```

I need to do the following join in linq method syntax:

```
select * from Claim c
left join Lookup l on 
(l.LFKeyID = c.FKeyID OR l.LFKeyID = 0)
AND (l.LCKeyID = c.CKeyID OR l.LCKeyID = 0)
AND (l.LICode = c.ICode OR l.LIName = c.IName)
```

I've tried the following, but it's only joining on the initial key and doesn't have the OR clause for the lookup key = 0. I'm completely stumped.

```
query = _context.Claim.Join(_context.Lookup, 
clm => clm.FKeyID, lk => lk.LFKeyID, (clm, lk) => new 
{ ... fields go here ... })
.DefaultIfEmpty().ToList();
```

In case anyone else is trying to accomplish this using method syntax, here is the solution thanks to the comment given:

```
var query = _context.Claim.Where(i => (various initial filter criteria))
.SelectMany(clm => _context.Lookup, (clm, lk) = new { clm, lk })
.Where(lk => (lk.LFKeyID == clm.FKeyID || lk.LFKeyID == 0)
            && (lk.LCKeyID == clm.CKeyID || lk.LCKeyID == 0)
            && (lk.LICode == clm.ICode || lk.LIName == clm.IName))
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
 .Select(s => new 
{
// list of fields
}).ToList();
```

Comment: I've always had better luck with from queries when using outer joins:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use other technique for LEFT JOIN described in [Complex Query Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#collection-selector-references-outer-in-a-where-clause)

```cs
var query = 
    from clm in _context.Claim
    from lk in _context.Lookup
        .Where(lk => (lk.LFKeyID == clm.FKeyID || lk.LFKeyID == 0)
            && (lk.LCKeyID == clm.CKeyID || lk.LCKeyID == 0)
            && (lk.LICode == clm.ICode || lk.LIName == clm.IName))
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new 
    {
        clm, // or specify fields precisely
        lk
    };
```

Comment: This looks very promising. I'm supposed to keep it in method syntax -- to do the multiple from statements in that syntax, would I use a .SelectMany() or is there some other way?  Thanks so much!

Comment: This looks complicated to create using method syntax.  [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=net-7.0) says that the default equality comparer, `Default` is used to compare the keys in the join, but you need an "OR". So I suppose you could create your own comparer.

Comment: I experimented with adding .SelectMany and it now works!  Thanks so much for the response -- it's ugly in method syntax, but it's working.  Appreciate it!

Comment: SelectMany is `from` `from` in query syntax. I never use Method chain syntax when work with several recordsets. It is ugly and unmaintainable.

Comment: I totally agree on the ugly and unmaintainable but it's required to use method at my job.

Comment: IMHO, dumb restriction. For complex queries it is nightmare.